Output is not displaying in the browser, but when I check the console it's showing
I followed this youtube tutorial and created a text generation model. I pretty much copied the same code just some slight modification. There's no error in the code but the output is not displaying when I click the generate buton. But it appears in the console.
This is the HTML Code
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Story Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <nav>
    <img src="/yt_logo.png" alt="YouTube Logo">
    <h1>Text Data Generator</h1>
  </nav>

  
  <div class="container">
    <form class="meta-form">
      <h2>Generate Text</h2>
      <label for="title">
        <span> Title:</span>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">generate story</button>
      </label>
    </form>
  
    <div class="description">
      <p>Your Story</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tags">
      <p>Facts</p>
    </div>
    
    
  </div><!-- end container -->

  <script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Following is the Index.js code
// forms
const metaForm = document.querySelector('.meta-form')


// output elements
const description = document.querySelector('.description p')
const tags = document.querySelector('.tags p')


// description and tags
metaForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const res = await fetch('/groq/meta', {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({title: metaForm.title.value}),
    method: 'POST'
  })
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log(data)  

  description.textContent = data.description.content
  tags.textContent = data.tags.content
})


Can anyone knows why it's not displaying the text in the browser?

Are there errors in console?  Maybe the response has a JSON structure different  than you expect.   Add console.log(data.description.content), just for starting to debug

No, there are no errors in the console. The output is generated in the console but it just not displaying in the browser. And when I add your reply code it shows undefined in the console.

Ok; so, the API isn't returning nothing suitable for description.textContent. Undefined, blank page, etc . Edit your question, and add the whole  object obtained with console.log(data)
